# Running Big Commerce's Stencil CLI on Windows 10

Tags: bigcommerce

I can not get Stencil to run for the life of me. I am using NVM to mange my version of node - I tried both 10.16 and 10.19.

I have reinstalled Stencil 2 or 3 times now and ever time I get the same error:

[image: gitbash errors]

WTF? Has anyone got this to successfully run on a Windows 10 machine? We originally had node 13.9 installed but I was getting the same errors so I figured it was because it was outside their "approved" versions. I spoke to their customer support and they told me that it should work with newer version but that they can't give it proper approval until it's goes through some process.

So I can't get this to work on any version......

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before installing nvm was a previous version of node installed? You'll need to uninstall nvm and node before installing nvm which can cause this. You can confirm which version of node is installed using `node --version`

Comment: Nope. :-( I uninstalled and reinstalled everything and get the same message.

Comment: You'll want to be sure that you didn't reinstall node from nodejs.org, you only want to end up with nvm controlling node. Just wanted to clarify on what we needed to reinstall :) In other words, there shouldn't be a program installed within the Windows control panel for Node.

You can also try using "which node" to see if this is pointing to the one you're expecting.

Comment: Ah, so remove Node completely and just use NVM. Gotcha.

Comment: I got a little farther along, but I'm getting an error that even with specifying using 32bit version of node I am getting an error that Node.js v@bigcommerce/stencil-cli.0.0 is only available in 32-bit. I'm going to reach out to their customer support on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing version 10 displayed after sending `node --version`? You can also try `where node` to make sure it's pointed to the correct one. To be sure only NVM is installed I would check the Windows Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs section, there shouldn't be anything installed named "Node".